# Chudnovsky Formula vs. Machin Type Formulae for Calculating $\pi$

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

In honor of recent $\pi$ Day, I found myself drawn into thinking about how modern calculation of $\pi$ is done. Both the approach via Machin-like formulae and the approach via the Chudnovsky formula involve series which generate accurate digits at a roughly linear rate in the number of terms. Yet, apparently, generally, the Chudnovsky formula far outperforms any Machin-like (or other known) approach at quickly calculating approximations of $\pi$. My question is, why is this? Is there a good theoretical reason to expect this?

Comment: isn't it all about the number of digits per iteration? 1.5 for Machin's formula (improved to 8 by Vega), 14 for Chudnovsky's formula.

Comment: Well, we could just as well say Machin's formula gives us a series producing 15 digits per term, just taking each term to be the bundling of 10 terms as previously understood. The analysis must be somewhat deeper than that, involving some understanding of the work going into calculating individual terms, and it's not clear to me exactly why this analysis should so prefer Chudnovsky. So I'm curious what's going on there in particular, but perhaps that part of it still essentially does come down to something like the 1.5 vs. 14 thing.

Comment: But I'm also curious about this: there's a whole general realm of Machin-type formulae (the angles whose tangents are rational comprise an additive group including 45°, and Machin-type formulae correspond to collections of angles of magnitude < 45° with sum a nonzero multiple of 45°, with smaller angles yielding faster convergence). Is there good reason why NO Machine-type formulae would be comparably computationally efficient to Chudnovsky, or is it just that none have been found yet?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the riddle is to consider the size of the rational number coefficients per term, which affect the speed of doing arithmetic.

If you bundle up 10 terms in the arctangent series with $x = 1/5$ (as in Machin's formula) you get

$$\sum_{i=10k}^{10k+9} \frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1} \frac{1}{5^{2i+1}} = \frac{2 \left(37560096153845760000000 k^9+186066937869820928000000
    k^8+398455946674439782400000 k^7+482970120763998238720000 k^6+364153120553964698624000 k^5+176546433993543523571200
    k^4+54825098616166830632960 k^3+10467740476445305028288 k^2+1108789091484167233008 k+49301381038520624049\right)}{5^{20 k+19} (4
    k+1) (4 k+3) (20 k+1) (20 k+3) (20 k+7) (20 k+9) (20 k+11) (20 k+13) (20 k+17) (20 k+19)}
$$
(where the power $5^{20}$ can be recycled from one group of terms to the next). This is clearly a lot more work to evaluate than the ratio

$$\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k} = -\frac{(2 k+1) (6 k+1) (6 k+5) (545140134 k+558731543)}{10939058860032000 (545140134k+13591409) (k+1)^3}$$

between terms in the Chudnovsky series.

The analysis is more or less the same whether you compute the terms in linear succession (which allows computing $d$ digits of $\pi$ in $d^{2+o(1)}$ time) or using binary splitting (which requires only $d^{1+o(1)}$ time, and is used by all high performance implementations).

For the same reason, the Ramanujan type series that yield even more digits per term than the Chudnovsky series are slower in practice because they have larger coefficients and/or require computing with number field elements. The Chudnovsky series happens to strike the best balance between rate of convergence and complexity of coefficients out of all known formulas. The difference is just a constant factor, however.

Comment: Ah. And is there theoretical reason to expect that no Machine-type formulae  ($\pi$ as a rational combination of arctangents of rationals in (-1, 1)) would have coefficients allowing comparably computationally efficiency to Chudnovsky, or is it just that none have been found yet?

Comment: Intuitively, I think the existence of Machin type formulas with varying efficiency is just a coincidence, so one should not expect much improvement over the simplest formula. On the other hand, the remarkable efficiency of the Chudnovsky formula is explained by the j-invariant and Heegner numbers. Compare this to how 355/113 is a good approximation to $\pi$ but $\log(640320^3+744)/\sqrt{163}$ is a remarkable one.

Answer (score 0):

@ Sridhar Ramesh. Computational efficiency of the Machin like formula is defined by Lehmer's measure (see eq. (31) for $e$ in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Machin-LikeFormulas.html, see also  https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Machin+like+formula). At small $e$ the Machin like formulas provide the convergence rate significantly greater than $14$ new digits of $\pi$ per term. However, the Chudnovsky formula, which convergence rate is 14 digits per term only, is found to be most efficient. Therefore it is still an open question if the Machin like formula for $\pi$ can be more efficient than the Chudnovsky formula for $\pi$.

I can only suggest that the FFT algorithm for the Chudnovsky formula requires relatively smaller algebraic manipulations to compute digits of $\pi$. Perhaps the FFT algorithm for the Machin like formulas has not been developed yet. This may be another reason.